# Get files in drive with certain file size VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a program that will scan through your entire C drive and then have it add the items with a certain file size to a listbox! I've been trying at this thing for hours and I really need some help on it! I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me!

Comment: I'm not going to allow you to scan through my entire C drive! Also, you should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Post some code of what you have tried before, and try to specify where it fails. Stack Overflow is not a forum where you chat your way to a solution. You have to ask a good, precise question, to get a good, precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private searchfilesVar As Long = 0
Private Sub searchF(dire As String)
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(dire)
        Dim diar1 As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
        For Each f As IO.FileInfo In diar1
            If f.Length > 3221225472 Then 'Length in bytes
                searchfilesVar += 1
            End If
        Next
        For Each d As IO.DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories
            searchF(d.FullName)
        Next
    End Sub
```

It will search subdirectories starting from the first you entered.